# C++ matrix and vector design

Tags: c++, class, matrix

I'm making custom vector and matrix class for numerical calculations.

I want to treat each row and column of the matrix as a vector. Also, I do not want to use extra memory, therefore, I made VectorView class which uses data in matrix directly(Like GSL library). Here is the outline of my matrix class.

```
class Matrix{
priavte:
    T data[];
    ....
public:
    VectorView row(int n);
    VectorView colum(int n);
};
```

And I define a function which uses VectorView.

```
myFunc(VectorView& v);
```

My VectorView class has some extra data, therefore I want to use VectorView as a reference to save memory.

However, I got a problem when I calling a function like this.

```
Matrix m;
...
...
myFunc(m.row(i));
```

The problem is that m.row(i) returns temporary object therefore I cannot use reference type to treat it. But

```
auto v = m.row(i);
myFunc(v);
```

this does not makes a error even though it is exactly same but not clear reason to use v. I want to use the above one. Is there an brilliant solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

`row` returns an rvalue reference (`VectorView&&`), which cannot be passed as a non-const lvalue reference (`VectorView&`). You can either redefine `myFunc` as `myFunc(const VectorView& v)` or `myFunc(VectorView&& v)`, depending on your requirements and the behaviour of `VectorView`.

If `myFunc` needs access to non-const members of `VectorView`, you'll need to define the latter, which will pass the returned value from `row` into `myFunc` using move semantics. However, since `VectorView` is just a "view" onto the original data, it possibly doesn't have (or need) any non-const members, in which case, you should use the former.

Answer (score 0):

use valarray and gslice

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/gslice/

N-D (including 2D) matrices are why Bjarne added gslices (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use Eigen

eigen.tuxfamily.org

is a header-only c++ matrix library with very good support and performance

Answer (score 0):

Guess your vector view contains only a pointer to original data and a integer for step (1 for row, n for column). In that case treat it as a value object is fine (as long as you make sure the life cycle of matrix is good). So if you want the syntax, you can just use value in myFunc. Like: myFunc(VectorView) ...

Answer (score 0):

Write two `VectorView`s: `VectorView` and `ConstVectorView`.  The first holds a view of a slice of data, and a method is `const` iff it does not change *which* slice you are looking at.  Changing members is ok in a `const` method of `VectorView`.

`ConstVectorView` is a view of a vector where changing the value of elements is illegal.  You can change what you are viewing with non-`const` methods, and you can access elements to read with `const` methods.

You should be able to construct a `ConstVectorView` from a `VectorView`.

Then, when you return a `VectorView`and pass it to a function, the function should either take it by value, or take it by `const&`.  If the function doesn't modify its contents, it takes a `ConstVectorView`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life simple, and stick to C-style semantics (this allows you to use the wealth of C linear algebra code available out there, and easy to use the fortran ones as well).

You state that you are concerned about using extra memory, but if you are simply concerned and do not have tight bounds, ensure you store the matrix in both row and column format. This will be crucial for getting any kind of performance out of common matrix operations (as you will be using whole cache lines at a time).

```
class Matrix{
private:
    T rowData[];
    T colData[];
    ...
public:
    T const * row(int n) const;
    T const * colum(int n) const;
    ...
};
```